# Limiting the pulse width of a PWM by using voltage divider and a single power supply

Tags: pwm, voltage-divider, potentiometer, duty-cycle, tl494

I'm using a Tl494 PWM and I want to limit the pulse width from 0% to 80% of the signal as maximum. How can I achieve this using a SINGLE 5v reference supply (I know it can be achieved  by using two supplies) and a voltage divider? 
I tried many combinations of potentiometer and resistor and I end up getting a pulse width out of this limit, that is, the duty ratio always is allowed to exceed the  80% limit. I want to prohibit the possibility of the device user exceeding that limit.

[image]

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: So let me clarify: Your control the PWM dutty cycle using a potentiometer, and now you want to limit the range of the potentiometer so that the duty cycle can only ever be between 0 and 80%, rather than 0 and 100%?

Comment: @DKNguyen Exactly.

Comment: Do you need the potentiomter vs duty cycle response to be linear?

Comment: It doesn't matter really. I just want to make sure that the end user won't be able to go over 80% since above this limit the device can burn out.

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing your circuit since it depends on how the potentiometer is interacting with the IC to control it. If you are lucky, then you can clamp the voltage at the potentiometer output pin with a diode so the voltage of the pot can never exceed the voltage that corresponds to 80% duty cycle.

Comment: @DKNguyen I only use the Feedback pin of the chip and the error amplifier pins are grounded.

Comment: @DKNguyen the voltage corresponding to 0.8 duty is 1 volt (of 5v Ref). The potentiometer would go the whole way and make it reaches zero volt between its wiper and the other terminal. Where can I connect the diode or zener to prevent that?

Comment: If using a zener, connected so it is pointing from ground to the output of your potentiometer to ground. No guarantees though since I don't know your circuit. A regular diode pointing from the pot output to some other voltage supply 0.7V less than the 80% voltage (to compensate for the voltage drop of the diode) also works.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I can only guess at your circuit, for now I will just post this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk3oIL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your situation is like the left one, you can add a resistor between the potentiometer and ground like the one at the right to limit its swing.

Comment: So, the wiper is connected to the IC input and the the potentiometer terminal 1 to the +5v and the terminal 3 to the 250 ohm, then the 250 ohm to ground. But doesn't that make the input to the IC zero when the wiper reaches its full range? because at full range the voltage drop between wiper and the 250 ohm terminal is zero... the wiper is at the same point as the teminal 3 (250 ohm teminal). isn't the voltage output of the potentiometer is across its wiper ( terminal 2) and the terminal 3?

Comment: @A.Ali You wrote, "I just want to make sure that the end user won't be able to go over 80% since above this limit the device can burn out," so I think some consideration of failure modes of potentiometers (which can vary substantially depending on construction details -- for example, different concerns exist amongst wirewound, cermet, and carbon) should be addressed if this is to be a product. The simple modification shown here may be inappropriate, depending on your product context. On a concept prototype, it looks fine, though.

Comment: @jonk It's not going to be a product. just a project but I don't want to burn the components used. Considering the simple modification here, is it work at all? it seems that the voltage difference across the potentiometer terminals would still reach zero when the wiper goes all the way from Terminal 1 (the supply) to the terminal 3 ( at which Terminal 2 voltage = Terminal 3 voltage, the difference is still zero). the 250 ohm resistor here only divides the 5 voltage supply but not preventing the voltage reaching zero possibility (hence the duty is 100%, obviously over the limit 80%).

Comment: @A.Ali It's just a voltage divider. Let \$R_\text{POT}\$ be the potentiometer resistance and let \$0 \le p\le 1\$ be a parameter representing the percent above the bottom lead, along the potentiometer resistance strip, that locates its wiper position. Let \$R_1=250\:\Omega\$ be the bottom resistor from evil's circuit. If \$r= \frac{R_1}{R_\text{POT}}=0.25\$ Then$$V_\text{wiper} = 5\: \text{V}\cdot\frac{p+r}{1+r}=5\: \text{V}\cdot\frac{p+0.25}{1.25}$$

Comment: @A.Ali No, with the values I listed the wiper will not go below 1 V.  Imagine a voltage divider using a 1 kΩ series resistor and 250 Ω resistor to ground.  I don't know what value your potentiometer is, but if you make the additional resistor 25% of the potentiometer value then you will reduce the swing by 1/5 (this is what Jonk is saying in his comment as well).

Comment: If you turn the pot all the way, so the wiper is at the same voltage as terminal 3, it won't be at ground, it will still be 250 Ω away from it.  In the right example, terminal 3 of the pot is at 1 V.

Comment: A danger remains if the 5V supply goes away and the rest of the circuit is still operating (separate supplies).

Comment: Big thanks to you, @jonk and Mr. evildemonic . This helped a lot.

Comment: @A.Ali I'm really glad it can work for you and glad that evildemonic quickly put up something easy and quick to apply in your case. It's nice when that happens! Best wishes!